# How do I define the hidden size and network architecture for a Long Short Term Memory (LSTM) Recurrent Neural Network (RNN)?

Tags: neural-networks, python, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am reading the PyTorch documentation on using LSTM to [classify names with a character-level RNN](http://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/char_rnn_classification_tutorial.html) and [generating names with a character-level RNN](http://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/char_rnn_generation_tutorial.html).

In the examples they show, the network's `hidden_size` is set to `128`. Why is that? How do they know that `128` makes the learning work? In general, is there a guiding principle (besides trial and error) that we may use to set this parameter's value? Will `128` work in general and transfer to other problem domains?

Also, I find that it is not clear why they define the [classification](http://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/char_rnn_classification_tutorial.html#creating-the-network) and [generation](http://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/char_rnn_generation_tutorial.html#creating-the-network) networks architectures as so. If we can transform our problem to the ones like they've demonstrated, will the network architectures be reasonable and/or applicable to use?

I realized that nearly identical questions ([here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/243509/how-to-set-the-dimension-of-hidden-states-for-recurrent-neural-network-rnn) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/278092/how-to-design-architecture-for-lstm-neural-network)) have been asked, but those are in general, and here, I am referring to concrete examples.

Answer (score 1):

> How do they know that 128 makes the learning work?

They probably tried a number of other configurations (say, 32, 64, 256, 512) units and found that 128 worked well. (It's possible that using more units works better, but they went with 128 for some other reason, such as speed of training.)

> In general, is there a guiding principle (besides trial and error) that we may use to set this parameter's value?

No.

> Will 128 work in general and transfer to other problem domains?

Probably not. Different problems present different challenges; not all problems are the same difficulty.